# Java advanced loop : what is (not) evaluated in the loop's header?

Tags: java, loops

I have the following code:

```
for (Attribute thisAttribute : factor.getAttributes()) {
// blabla
}
```

where `factor.getAttributes()` returns `List<Attribute>`.

Apparently, there is only one initial call to `factor.getAttributes()` and then the traversal starts. However, I don't understand why there is only one call. If I were to include a function call in the header of a regular `for()` loop, I believe it would be evaluated at each iteration. In that respect, how and why is the advanced loop different?

Comment: For each loop is a bit different for normal for loop.
You need to understand that a for each loop we get the collection and use the iterator to loop though it.

Comment: So how does JVM know that I mean to get the collection only once in the beginning?

Comment: Depends on the part of the loop head you're talking about for how often something is called. In a classic loop, `for (int i = getStartInt(); i < checkLimit(); i++)`, the `getStartInt` method is only called once (when the loop first starts), while `checkLimit` is called at the beginning of each iteration. Enhanced `for` loops are a little different, as they use [`Iterator`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), which [`List`s have](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator%28%29).

Comment: @James Is there any specific reason you want `factor.getAttributes()` to be called in every iteration?

Comment: Of course I don't. I works the way I want, but I'd like to know why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think of it as getting translated to something like:

```
{
    Iterator<Attribute> it = factor.getAttributes().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Attribute thisAttribute = it.next();
        // loop body here
    }
}
```

The compiler knows it gets an Iterable, it can get the Iterator from it once and use it within the loop.

It turns out the [Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) seems to agree, it says:

> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:

```
for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
    {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier =
        (TargetType) #i.next();
    Statement
}
```

Comment: Nitpicking: Shouldn't that be `Iterator<Attribute> it = factor.getAttributes().terator();`?

Comment: JLS reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

Comment: Sure ! when we think of more complicated stuff we tend to miss trivial things ;) :P